# shell script compare numbers return illegal number

Tags: shell

I have a script that simply needs to check a timestamp with another timestamp in an if-statement.

However, it constantly returns an Illegal number

```
currentTime=$(($(date +%s) -d ))
cutoffTime=$((currentTime - 604800))
```

`cutoffTime` is the first variable to compare

```
time="$(echo $notes | grep -oP '^[0-9]{0,10}')"
```

`time` is the second variable to compare and is parsed from a `string`.

The if-statement looks like this

```
if [ $(($time)) -lt "$cuttofTime" ];
```

but even if I try

```
if [ "$time" -lt "$cuttofTime" ];
```

or

```
 if [ "$time" < "$cuttofTime" ];
```

It will still say 'Illegal number'. I have no clue why it says illegal number when converting `$time` to a number in the first if-statement. 
What is the proper way to do this in shell scripts and why does it state it is an illegal number?

Comment: First try having the correct name: `cutoffTime` (your if statements have an extra "t" and one less "f"). If that doesn't fix it, try `if [[ $time -lt $cutoffTime ]];`

Comment: What does `$notes` look like? In any case, `$time` seems to already be a number, so you should use just `$time` instead of `$(($time))`; the latter will return exit status 0 and not the value of `$time`.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a typo: `$cuttofTime` instead of `$cutoffTime`. The wrongly spelled one would expand to the empty string.

Comment: The typo was only in pasting my code here, so that didn't make any difference. I tried 'if [[ $time -lt $cutoffTime ]];' but that only returns 'not found'

Comment: Running your script with `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript`, and thus logging execution with values and line numbers, is a useful place to start. That way we'll *know* if something isn't expanding to what you think it does.

Comment: (and perhaps you can update the question to include those actual real-live values for which you get actual real-live failures).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when running the script with `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript` it actually works like it should. When running it directly, it fails with `[[: not found`

Comment: @terw_dan, that means when you "run it directly" you aren't using bash as the interpreter. `/bin/sh` isn't adequate to scripts using bash extensions. To be parsed with bash, a script needs to start with `#!/bin/bash`, and not be explicitly invoked with `sh`.